# How to compare two numpy arrays with some NaN values?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, compare

I need to compare some numpy arrays which should have the same elements in the same order, excepting for some NaN values in the second one.

I need a function more or less like this:

```
def func( array1, array2 ):
    if ???:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**Example:**

```
x = np.array( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] )
y = np.array( [ 11, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] )
z = np.array( [ 1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5] )

func( x, z ) # returns True
func( y, z ) # returns False
```

The arrays have always the same length and the NaN values are always in the third one (x and y have always numbers only). I can imagine there is a function or something already, but I just don't find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You do not specify when the two arrays are equal...  What if the second has `nan`. Should these be ignored?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My bad, corrected already ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use masked arrays, which have the behaviour you're asking for when combined with `np.all`:

```
zm = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(z), z)

np.all(x == zm) # returns True
np.all(y == zm) # returns False
```

Or you could just write out your logic explicitly, noting that numpy has to use `|` instead of `or`, and the difference in operator precedence that results:

```
def func(a, b):
    return np.all((a == b) | np.isnan(a) | np.isnan(b))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to check for equality (or closeness to within a given tolerance -- this is particularly useful when comparing floats) and use [`isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) to check for NaNs in the second array. 
Combine the two with bitwise-or (`|`), and use `all` to demand every pair is either close or contains a NaN to obtain the desired result:

```
In [62]: np.isclose(x,z)
Out[62]: array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [63]: np.isnan(z)
Out[63]: array([False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

---

So you could use:

```
def func(a, b):
    return (np.isclose(a, b) | np.isnan(b)).all()


In [67]: func(x, z)
Out[67]: True

In [68]: func(y, z)
Out[68]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
from math import isnan

def fun(array1,array2):
    return all(isnan(x) or isnan(y) or x == y for x,y in zip(array1,array2))
```

This function works in both directions (if there are `NaN`s in the first list, these are also ignored). If you do not want that (which is a bit odd since equality usually works bidirectional). You can define:

```
from math import isnan

def fun(array1,array2):
    return all(isnan(y) or x == y for x,y in zip(array1,array2))
```

The code works as follows: we use `zip` to emit tuples of elements of both arrays. Next we check if either the element of the first list is NaN, or the second, or they are equal.

Given you want to write a really elegant function, you better also perform a length check:

```
from math import isnan

def fun(array1,array2):
    return len(array1) == len(array2) and all(isnan(y) or x == y for x,y in zip(array1,array2))
```

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.islcose()` now provides an argument `equal_nan` for this case!

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.isclose([1.0, np.nan], [1.0, np.nan])
array([ True, False])
>>> np.isclose([1.0, np.nan], [1.0, np.nan], equal_nan=True)
array([ True,  True])
```

docs https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not address the question, because it is not about comparing NaN values among themselves